# How to create Key value from the folder absolute names with condition

Tags: python, dictionary

My output is below

Its a generator output (listoffiles)

```
for i in listoffiles:
    print (files)
```

Output

```
    test1/
    test1/Code.csv
    test2/
    test2/anomaly.csv
    test2/an.csv
    test3
    test4
```

I need to generate a dictionary if and only if for anything after /, you can see there is no keys test3 and test4 inside the output

Expected

`{'test1' :'Code.csv', 'test2':['anomaly.csv','an.csv']}`

Comment: test1/Code.csv is not an absolute name, is relative, an absolute would be `/test1/Code.csv.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)

for f in listoffiles:
    if "/" in f:
        split_ = f.split("/")

        # skip if leaf is empty
        if not split_[1]:
            continue

        result[split_[0]].append(split_[1])
```

Another solution with some help of `itertools.groupby`,

```
from itertools import groupby

filter_ = filter(lambda x : "/" in x and x.split("/")[1], listoffiles)

print(
    {k : [vv.split("/")[1] for vv in v]
     for k,v in groupby(filter_, key=lambda x : x.split("/")[0])}
)
```

---

```
{'test1': ['Code.csv'], 'test2': ['anomaly.csv', 'an.csv']}
```

Answer (score 0):

does the following work for you?

```
import re
file_dict = {}

for file in listoffiles:
    m = re.search(r"(\S*)\/(\S*)",file).groups()

    if m is None:
        continue 
    
    dir_name, file_name = m.groups()
    if file_name == "":
        continue

    if not file_dict.get(dir_name):
        file_dict[dir_name] = file_name
    elif type(file_dict[dir_name]) == list:
        file_dict[dir_name].appendUfile_name
    else:
        file_dict[dir_name] = [file_dict[dir_name], file_name]
```